# jquery selecting next element from $(this) position

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following snipped of my page:

```
<div class="radio-group">
<input type="radio" name="group1" checked="checked" id="option1" value="option1"/>
<label for="option1">option1</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="option2" value="option2"/>
<label for="option2">option2</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="option3" value="option3"/>
<label for="option3">option3</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="option4" value="option4"/>
<label for="option4">option4</label>
</div>
```

and this javascript code to select the hidden input after a click in the radios:

```
$("input[type='radio']").live("change", function () {        
    var el = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    el.value = this.value;
});
```

I want to write the line

```
var el = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
```

in a jQuery way. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input[type='radio']").live("change", function () {        
    var el = $(this).parent().next();
    el.val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Use `el.val(this.value);` since `el` is a jQuery element. However, `this.value` doesn't contain any information if the element is checked or not!

Answer (score 5):

```
var el = $(this).parent().next().find("input[type='radio']");
el.val(this.value);
```

very easy. :)

#### Edit

lol didn't pay enough attention to the markup. :P fixed.

Comment: The above will select the next sibling of `this`, not the next sibling of `this.parentNode` as the OP's code will!

Comment: @Jon Saw that after the down vote :P but thanks for pointing it out. already fixed.

Comment: @Jon oh I didn't assume that, but I honestly don't mind the downvote because it made me go back and look :P

Answer (score 3):

```
var el = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
```

translates to

```
var $el = $(this).parent().next();
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery's this, also note that you can filter the next selector (in case something goes wrong with your code)

```
var el = $(this).next('input[type="hidden"]');
```

Comment: I like this style but I get no results with this.